# How to select items which is displayed in Grid result

Tags: html, selenium

```
<DIV class=x-grid3-scroller id=ext-gen742>
<DIV class=x-grid3-body id=ext-gen743>
<DIV class=x-grid3-row  x-grid3-row-first x-grid3-row-last >
<TABLE class=x-grid3-row-table>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD> class=x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-0 x-grid3-cell-first 
<td> class=x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-1 
<td> class=x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-2
<td> class=x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-3
```

Once I click on any one of these TD values via GUI, it should be selected in the search field in the form.

Could any one help meregarding this.

Comment: I'd like to help, but I'm having trouble understanding your question. What does the mass of class=... mean? What are you looking to test with Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your asking, but based off the title I'm going to give this example as an answer:

**table**

```
abc def
foo bar
jkl mno
```

**XPath**

```
//tr[td/text()='foo']/td[2]
```

This would select bar with the following breakdown.

find any row[that has a column, with text that is ‘foo’] with a column [that is the second]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your asking, but based off the title I'm going to give this example as an answer:

**table**

```
abc def
foo bar
jkl mno
```

**XPath**

```
//tr[td/text()='foo']/td[2]
```

This would select bar with the following breakdown.

find any row[that has a column, with text that is ‘foo’] with a column [that is the second]