# How to select row from grid which has following properties

Tags: selenium

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to select items which is displayed in Grid result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921001/how-to-select-items-which-is-displayed-in-grid-result)

class=x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-0 x-grid3-cell-first 
 class=x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-1 
 class=x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-2
 class=x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-3

Once I click on any one of these TD values via GUI, it should be selected in the search field in the form.

Could any one help meregarding this.